# Bootstrap 4, make second column content change depending where have we scrolled on 1st column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I have 2 columns in one row, one is for main content and second one next to it is for code preview for that main content, what I want to do is that second column would switch content that I set to once I scroll down to specific part of column one. The column one in this code is the white one where the content is suppsed to be, and the dark column is where the code should be displayed dependt on where are you on white column

Edit Code:

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container-flex">
        <!-- navbar top-->
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">IP Intelligence</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 linknav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="input/input.html">Input</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="output/output.html">Output</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="flags/flags.html">Flags</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="flags/flags.html#error">Error Codes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#inputSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Input</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="inputSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="input/input.html">Input</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="input/input.html">Optional Input Settings</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#outputSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Output</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="outputSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Expected Output</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Interpretation of the Results</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Variations of Implementation</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="flags/flags.html">Comparing Flags</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="flags/flags.html#error">Error Codes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </nav>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex content" style="width: 40%">
            <div class="col">
            <!--main page-->
            <div class="cont">
              <h1>Usage & Implementation</h1>
              <h3>Web Interface</h3>
              <p>The web interface allows you to quickly lookup IPs without touching any code. It is assumed that the IP you're looking up has made requests to your services on an application level. The web interface uses flags=f which requests full bad IP detection including compromised systems. If you wish to skip full bad IP detection, please use the API instead. A full lookup might take up to 5 seconds to complete because results are generated in real-time.</p>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex content" style="width: 40%">

            <div class="col bg-dark">
              <!--Code Editor-->
              <h2 class="codep">Code Preview</h2>
              <div class="neapolitan"/>

              <div class="code">
                <code>
                    this is code
                </code>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
  </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
  }

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.stay-open {display:block !important;}

.codep {
   color: #f0ad4e;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.code {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.neapolitan {
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    height:1px;
    content:'';
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
}

.cont{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.cont h3 h2 h6{
  padding-top: 20px;

}

.cont p{
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.label-default {

    background-color: #777;

}
.label {

    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;

}
.cont li {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #696969;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.cont ul{
  padding-left: 40px;

}

.cont b{

}

.ind{
}
.cont-t{
  font-size: 11px;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */



#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #343a40;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}


#sidebar ul.components {
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #343a40;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f0ad4e;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #292b2c;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.linknav {
  padding-left: 72px;
}

.linknav a{
  display:inline;
  margin-right:1.5em;
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us a code snippet? what you have done so far

Comment: Yes, I have edited post and added some code with extra info

Comment: You probably will divide the content into sections, check which section is in the viewport and show corresponding data on the right section.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#codeSection').scroll(function(){

 ($('#previewCode').text($('#codeSection').text()).css('color','white'));
});
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <!-- navbar top-->
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">IP Intelligence</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 linknav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="input/input.html">Input</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="output/output.html">Output</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="flags/flags.html">Flags</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="flags/flags.html#error">Error Codes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#inputSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Input</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="inputSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="input/input.html">Input</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="input/input.html">Optional Input Settings</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#outputSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Output</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="outputSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Expected Output</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Interpretation of the Results</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="output/output.html">Variations of Implementation</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="flags/flags.html">Comparing Flags</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="flags/flags.html#error">Error Codes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </nav>
        <div  class="container-flex d-flex content" style="width: 40%; height:120px">
            <div class="col">
            <!--main page-->
            <div class="cont" id="codeSection" style="overflow:scroll;height:250px">
              <h1>Usage & Implementation</h1>
              <h3>Web Interface</h3>
              <p>The web interface allows you to quickly lookup IPs without touching any code. It is assumed that the IP you're looking up has made requests to your services on an application level. The web interface uses flags=f which requests full bad IP detection including compromised systems. If you wish to skip full bad IP detection, please use the API instead. A full lookup might take up to 5 seconds to complete because results are generated in real-time.</p>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container-flex d-flex content" style="width: 40%">

            <div class="col bg-dark">
              <!--Code Editor-->
              <h2 class="codep">Code Preview</h2>
              <div class="neapolitan"/>

              <div id='previewCode' class="code">
                <code>
                    this is code
                </code>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>


      </div>
  </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

use jquery's scroll function https://api.jquery.com/scroll/. this will trigger once you scroll your div with the code section.
for this example to work i have added an id to code section and also have done some alteration to make codesection div scrollable. (see console for message on scroll).

so on scroll you can also check page offset and can set value to preview screen as needed..

Comment: I didn't get it, how do I assign it? I mean yeah I added script and changed divs, but how to assign so the content changes?

Comment: you can simply add id attribute to the preview div and add or append content to it under scroll event in js. means you logic to display content will comes under scroll event.

Comment: could you show an example? sorry Im really bad at javascript and scripting in general

Comment: try this now. it will show you the content of div one to div other

Comment: It works, but doesn't work applied on other code snippets

Comment: it doesn't work once I upload it on my computer, I have same files and evyrhting but it it doesnt work

Comment: check your browser console, is it throwing any error and of yes what it is?

Comment: one error:  ReferenceError: $ is not defined[Learn More] script.js:1:1

    <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/scroll/script.js:1

Comment: it may be due to your jquery file is not properly linked